# How to resolve Subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

So currently have my code here trying to make a trigger for it, but this is just the sql query within the trigger at the moment.

Keeps giving me the #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
Update Agent 
Set ListingsSold=ListingsSold+1
Where (Select Availability
   From Property
   Where AgentID=Agent.AgentID)='N' AND (SELECT AgentID
       FROM Property
       Where AgentID=Agent.AgentID)=Agent.AgentID
```

I just want ListingsSold to increment by 1 in the Agent table when a property is sold (or its Availability changes from 'Y' to 'N' and I need it to update for the appropriate Agent with AgentID that corresponds to the Property they are selling.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You have made your query very complex to understand, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. But whatever you mentioned in your post, I felt, you should have used `INNER JOIN` instead.

```
UPDATE Agent AS A
INNER JOIN Property AS P ON A.AgentID = P.AgentID
SET ListingsSold = ListingsSold + 1
WHERE Availability = 'N'
```